# Can I use a 250 VAC socket for 120V power?

Tags: power, voltage, socket

I live in canada and I'm trying to build some DIY audio gear.

I'm using a toroid http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VPT30-830/237-1326-ND/2090064 (115, 2x15v)

And this socket to go with it
http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Schurter/62202100/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtz8P%2feuiupSXCZijoDTJT7CpNaaNTPFbk%3d

Is this okay? How about the fuse? Do I need to use a 250v 10A fuse?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

P.S. (residential voltage on canada is 120v)

Answer (score 1):

That connector is rated to handle up to 250 Volts at 10 Amp.

It is the same type of connector that is used on desktop computers and many other things these days.  It is certainly appropriate to use it for 120 VAC, as we have in Canada.

The fuses should be rated to suit your application, but not more than 10 Amp.

Comment: Note that cables exist that connect these receptacles to 250V, so it may be a good idea to have a red "120V" sticker somewhere nearby.

Comment: @SimonRichter: a mating cable with a 240V connector would be very rare in Canada, as would be a 240V outlet. 240 V is only used for electric stoves, clothes dryers, and other high-power devices.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a "250V socket", that is a socket *capable of handling 250V*. You'll be fine using it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! When it's labeled that it has a "rating of" 250v does that essentially mean it can "handle"?

Comment: It depends on the part in question.