# Will a filtered 250V IEC socket still work given 110V?

Tags: ac, filter, mains, socket

I have a very nice IEC socket I got at a swap meet a few years back:

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Schurter/43025001/?qs=%2fha2pyFadujsDnoxV1Y8VQWgys%252bCu2GOjmVWnETFUeE%3d

It has an integrated switch and filter, and I would like to incorporate it into my 3D printer build. However, according to the spec sheet ([link](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/358/typ_kfb1-45837.pdf)), this socket is designed for 250V. I live in the USA, and our standard wall voltage is 110V.

My question is:
Will this socket still work for my application? If the filtering circuit isn't provided the full 250V, will it still produce a filtered 110V sine wave on the other side? If not, I'll need to go hunting for another socket/switch combo.

Comment: Similar to the following question, but with an integrated filtering circuit: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135153/can-i-use-a-250-vac-socket-for-120v-power

Comment: 250 V is the maximum voltage. You are allowed to use it to any voltage between 0-250 Vac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the spec sheet of your link, there are ratings for both 50 and 60 Hz:

Ratings IEC 1 - 10 A @ Ta 40 °C / 250 VAC; 50 Hz

Ratings UL/CSA 1 - 10 A @ Ta 40 °C / 125 VAC; 60 Hz

Those parts are used by companies in Europe and USA to build electronic devices for the world market which are exported from Europe to USA or from USA to Europe.

But there are different versions of this socket for currents of 1, 2, 4, 6 and 10 A, I hope you got the right one for your project.

If you look at the diagramms for attenuation, they all start at 10 kHz, there is no difference for 50 and 60 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will definitely work well with 110V.
From the datasheet of the one that you specified it sais:

> Ratings UL/CSA 1 - 10 A @ Ta 40 °C / 125 VAC; 60 Hz

The most important specs you should look at are Rated Current (1 A, 3 A, 6 A, 10 A, 15 A…) and Type (EMI, EMI/RFI, RFI, IEC,…).